# Take snapshot of video in Qt Multimedia

Tags: qt, video, snapshot, qmediaplayer, qtmultimedia

Is it possible to take snapshot of a video in [Qt Multimedia](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-index.html)? how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the platform but what you can probably do is to use a [`QMediaPlayer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html), set a subclassed video surface via [`setVideoOutput`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#setVideoOutput-2), and get the frame data from the [`QVideoFrame`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoframe.html) passed in the [`present`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractvideosurface.html#present) method. You'll then have to deal with the frame format and to map if those are not in CPU memory.

However, depending on your need, I would use ffmpeg/libav to get a frame from a specific position.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Documentation here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#grabToImage-method)

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtMultimedia 5.0

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 480
    height: 800

    MediaPlayer {    
        id: player
        source: "file:///location/of/some/video.mp4"
        autoPlay: false            
    }

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        VideoOutput {
            id: output
            source: player
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true                
        }

        Row {
            id: buttonsRow
            height: 100
            spacing: 20
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            Layout.margins: 10                

            Button {
                id: playPauseButton
                text: player.playbackState === MediaPlayer.PlayingState ? "Pause" : "Play"
                onClicked: {
                    var playing = player.playbackState === MediaPlayer.PlayingState;
                    playing ? player.pause() : player.play();
                }
            }                
            Button {
                text: "Snapshot"
                onClicked: {
                    output.grabToImage(function(image) {
                        console.log("Called...", arguments)
                        image.saveToFile("screen.png"); // save happens here
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```